# Вопрос о склонении

Tags: склонение, падежи, глаголы, названия, род

Название организации - ООО ТОРГОВАЯ ФИРМА "РОМАШКА".
Скажите, пожалуйста, верно ли склонять следующим образом: "директор ООО ТОРГОВОЙ ФИРМЫ "РОМАШКА", "написать в ООО ТОРГОВУЮ ФИРМУ "РОМАШКА"?
И с каким словом правильно согласовывать глагол, с "обществом" или с "фирмой": "ООО ТОРГОВАЯ ФИРМА "РОМАШКА" являлось участником конференции" или "ООО ТОРГОВАЯ ФИРМА "РОМАШКА" являлась участником конференции"?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ваше склонение верно: *директор ООО ТОРГОВОЙ ФИРМЫ "РОМАШКА"*. Название в кавычках пишется в именительном падеже, если имеется родовое слово (см. соответствующие ответы [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F)).
2. Мне кажется, опорное слово тут будет "Фирма", а не "Общество", но я не знаю, есть ли на этот счёт правила.